# Django - FileField won't upload to database

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-database

I'm trying to upload some file with a `FileField` but when I hit the submit button and run the `form.save()` I have a new line in my database table but the file I tried to upload is not there.

I've been searching for some time to solve my problem but the only thing I've seen is about the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, but as you can see in the files bellow, I already have it ...

**views.py**

```py
class AdminFichiersPhyto(CreateView):
    template_name = 'phyto/phyto_admin_fichiers.html'
    model = models.PhytoFile
    fields = ['general_treatment', 'other']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("GONNA SAVE")
        form.save()
        if self.request.POST.get('autre'):
            print("autre")
            # gonna add some code to read the 'other' file
        if self.request.POST.get('trtm_gen'):
            print("traitement généraux")
            # gonna add some code to read the 'general_treatment' file
```

**phyto_admin_fichiers.html**

```html
{% block forms %}

{% if user.is_staff%}

    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
            <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 22%; text-align: center"><b>Traitements généraux</b>{{ form.general_treatment }}</div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center"><b>Autres traitements</b>{{ form.other }}</div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <p style="margin-top: 2%">
     <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Synchronisation Traitements généraux" name="trtm_gen"/>
     <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Synchronisation Autre" name="autre"/>
    </p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```py
class PhytoFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.PhytoFile
        fields = ['general_treatment', 'other']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PhytoFileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**models.py**

```py
class PhytoFile(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField("Date", default = datetime.datetime.now)
    general_treatment = models.FileField("Traitements généraux", upload_to='fichiers_phyto/', blank=True, null=True)
    other = models.FileField("Autres traitements", upload_to='fichiers_phyto/', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Liste - Fichier phyto"
        verbose_name_plural = "Liste - Fichiers phyto"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

But when even if it doesn't work via the form I can upload files thanks to the admin page.
I really hope one of you will have the solution to help me, I've been stucked for a while now ...

**EDIT** *after Akhilendra answer*

There is the lastest code I have:

**views.py**

```py
class AdminFichiersPhyto(View):
    template_name = 'phyto/phyto_admin_fichiers.html'
    form = forms.PhytoFileForm()

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = forms.PhytoFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.save()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form})
```

**phyto_admin_fichiers.html**

```html
{% block forms %}

{% if user.is_staff%}

    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
            <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 22%; text-align: center"><b>Traitements généraux</b>{{ form.general_treatment }}</div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center"><b>Autres traitements</b>{{ form.other }}</div>
        </fieldset>

      <p style="margin-top: 2%">
        <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Synchronisation Traitements généraux" name="trtm_gen"/>
        <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Synchronisation Autre" name="autre"/>
      </p>

    </form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

***forms.py** and **models.py** didn't change*

**EDIT *SOLUTION***

With Akhliendra we dug deeper into my problem and we finaly discovered that the problem came from the inheritance of templates, which would override the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. So in order to fix that I created a duplicate of the parent template and I added the `enctype` part in the overriding form tag. Hope this edit would help some people ;)

Comment: Check your MEDIA_ROOT  in setting.py. Is it okay?

Comment: @Akhilendra there is my MEDIA_ROOT: `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')`
And you should know that I can upload files via the admin page, so I think it's okay ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `submit` button should within `<form>` Tag, And also `{% csrf_token %}`

```
{% block forms %}

{% if user.is_staff%}

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <fieldset>
     <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 22%; text-align: center"> <b>Traitements généraux</b>{{
         form.general_treatment }}
     </div>
     <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center"><b>Autres traitements</b>{{ form.other }}</div>
 </fieldset>
 <p style="margin-top: 2%">
     <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
            value="Synchronisation Traitements généraux" name="trtm_gen"/>
     <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
            value="Synchronisation Autre" name="autre"/>
 </p>
    </form>
   {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Now come to `view`.

```
class AdminFichiersPhyto(View):
    template_name = "phyto/phyto_admin_fichiers.html"
    form = PhytoForm()

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = PhytoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.save()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form})
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Gonna try that, i'll let you know if I manage to make it work ;)

Comment: sure, If it works, don't forget to mark  as correct. :P

Comment: I changed everything you told me to change, the line is still created but the file is not uploaded ... I really don't understand why ^^'

Comment: Hi there ! Sorry to bother you again, but do you have any idea where my problem come from with this updated code ? I'm still stuck and it starting to get on my nerves ^^'

Comment: Are you able to share you screen, So i can check end to end. use any sharing application team-viewer or Anydesk.

Comment: I'll see what I can do for that on my Debian, I'll keep you noticed really soon ! thanks for you help ^_^

Comment: Sorry, went for lunch ... Are you up to do it now ?

Comment: Here you have my code: 630 026 598, I'll keep it up for some time